# ASP.NET Development Server permissions and Network Resources

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, iis

My ASP.NET 4.0 Web App is unable to access Network Printers, while debugging on VS 2010.  It can access local printers.  Seems like it may be a permissions issue.  Since VS2010 Debugging runs on ASP.NET Development Server, it must be running under the account I used to log into Windows, right?  Does that user need to be added as an Admin in that printers users? Is there any account that I can impersonate to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, debugging through Visual Studio means all of your code runs with the same rights as the user logged in to windows. On the server, you will need to setup impersonation and/or setup your Application Pool to run as a user who has access to print on these printers.

I recommend you setup a dedicated domain account (like domain\yourapp-impers-user) and either set the Application Pool to use that, or setup impersonation in your web.config. Then on the print server, you simply grant that user account the necessary permissions.

Comment: For impersonation, I just do <identity impersonate="true" userName="something" password="something" /> under System.Web, right? How do I setup my Application Pool to run as a particular user?

Comment: Thats correct for impersonation you may end up with `<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="something" />` -- you configure the Application Pool through the IIS MMC. Its under the advanced "properties" of your AppPool.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of impersonation

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;

    public partial class Main : PageBase
    {

    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {

            if (impersonateValidUser("Username", "Domain", "Password"))
            {
                //Your code under a specific user here.
            }

        }
    }

    private bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    if (impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        return false;
    }

    private void undoImpersonation()
    {
        impersonationContext.Undo();
    }
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

without knowing for sure, you can try to impersonate the Network Service, or of course your own domain account which should always work.